# Repeat columns as rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
   Fruit      January Shipments   January Sales   February Shipments   February Sales  
 ------------ ------------------- --------------- -------------------- ---------------- 
  Apple                      30              11                   18               31   
  Banana                     12              49                   39               14   
  Pear                       25              50                   44               21   
  Kiwi                       41              25                   10               25   
  Strawberry                 11              33                   35               50
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
 Fruit       Month     Shipments   Sales  
 ------------ ---------- ----------- ------- 
  Apple        January          30      11   
  Banana       January          12      49   
  Pear         January          25      50   
  Kiwi         January          41      25   
  Strawberry   January          11      33   
  Apple        February         18      31   
  Banana       February         39      14   
  Pear         February         44      21   
  Kiwi         February         10      25   
  Strawberry   February         35      50
```

I've tried pandas.pivot and pandas.pivot_table and had no luck. I'm in the process of creating two dataframes (Fruit/Month/Shipments) and (Fruit/Month/Sales), and concatenating the two into one with a loop, but I was hoping for a easier way to do this.

Comment: Might want `wide_to_long`

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you for this library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use modify the column to a multi level then use `stack`. Let suppose your dataframe is called df. First set the column Fruit as index, then define the multilevel columns:

```
df = df.set_index('Fruit')
# manual way to create the multiindex columns
#df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['January','February'],
#                                         ['Shipments','Sales']], names=['Month',None])
# more general way to create the multiindex columns thanks to @Scott Boston
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
df.columns.names = ['Month',None]
```

your data looks like:

```
Month        January        February      
           Shipments Sales Shipments Sales
Fruit                                     
Apple             30    11        18    31
Banana            12    49        39    14
Pear              25    50        44    21
Kiwi              41    25        10    25
Strawberry        11    33        35    50
```

Now you can use `stack` on level 0 and `reset_index`

```
df_output = df.stack(0).reset_index()
```

which gives

```
        Fruit     Month  Sales  Shipments
0       Apple  February     31         18
1       Apple   January     11         30
2      Banana  February     14         39
3      Banana   January     49         12
4        Pear  February     21         44
5        Pear   January     50         25
6        Kiwi  February     25         10
7        Kiwi   January     25         41
8  Strawberry  February     50         35
9  Strawberry   January     33         11
```

Finally, if you want a specific order for values in the column Month you can use `pd.Categorical`:

```
df_output['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df_output['Month'].tolist(), ordered=True,
                                    categories=['January','February'])
```

setting that January is before February when sorting. Now, doing

```
df_output = df_output.sort_values(['Month'])
```

gives the result:

```
        Fruit     Month  Sales  Shipments
1       Apple   January     11         30
3      Banana   January     49         12
5        Pear   January     50         25
7        Kiwi   January     25         41
9  Strawberry   January     33         11
0       Apple  February     31         18
2      Banana  February     14         39
4        Pear  February     21         44
6        Kiwi  February     25         10
8  Strawberry  February     50         35
```

I see it's not exactly the expected output (order in Fruit column and order of columns) but both can be easily change if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what I need! My real dataset is much larger however (Multiple 'fruit' columns and about 30 'Sales/Shipments' columns, so I hope this method will work on that.

Comment: A quicker way to MultiIndex columns is just to use split with expand=True.  `df_out.columns = df_out.columns.str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks, I added this more general way for multiindex columns

Answer (score 1):

How to use `pd.wide_to_long` as @user3483203 suggests.

```
df1 = df.set_index('Fruit')

#First we have to so column renaming use multiindex column headers and swapping levels.
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split(expand=True)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)

#Reset index and use pd.wide_to_long:
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df1, ['Shipments','Sales'], 'Fruit', 'Month','_','\w+')\
           .reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
        Fruit     Month  Shipments  Sales
0       Apple   January       30.0   11.0
1      Banana   January       12.0   49.0
2        Pear   January       25.0   50.0
3        Kiwi   January       41.0   25.0
4  Strawberry   January       11.0   33.0
5       Apple  February       18.0   31.0
6      Banana  February       39.0   14.0
7        Pear  February       44.0   21.0
8        Kiwi  February       10.0   25.0
9  Strawberry  February       35.0   50.0
```